# Ruby operator precedence

Tags: ruby

If I do `x**2.to_s` in irb, where x is an integer, I get the error message:

> TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum

I'm guessing this is because the code is interpreted as `x**(2.to_s)`. But when I searched for a table of Ruby operator precedence, I got array access as first with exponentiation as second. The dot operator was nowhere to be found (if it can be considered one). Am I correct with this interpretation and if so, where is this behavior defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` is *integer*, then `x**2.to_s` is `x.**(2.to_s)`. Because [`Fixnum#**`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-2A-2A) method exist. In your case `**` is a method, not an operator.

In this case, no operator *precedence and associativity* comes into existence.

In the expression - `x.**(2.to_s)`

- `x` is `Fixnum` object.
- `**` is a method called on `x`.
- `2.to_s` is simply an expression, which will be evaluated first, and passed as an argument to the method `**`.

My answer is as per your example. But there are several **edge** cases in Ruby. Just to get the taste of those, give some time to read this thread [*why does `a + f b` not parse?*](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2762669).

Comment: `x**y` is *always* a method call. Everything in Ruby is.

Comment: @tadman *Everything in Ruby is*.. After that what ? I think you forgot to write. Could you please ? :-)

Comment: Everything in Ruby is a method call.

Comment: @tadman Thank you.. I knew *everything in Ruby object*. But now I learnt a new phrase..

Comment: It's pretty lazy grammar on my part. Sorry about the ambiguity. Since everything in Ruby is an object, the way you interact with those objects is through method calls. This is unlike other languages where `2+3` is not a method call, but a low-level operation. In Ruby that's always equivalent to `2.send(:+, 3)` where `Fixnum#+` can be redefined if you like.

Comment: @tadman My English also sucks.. But I got your point from the second comment of yours.